# Vite building in console, but failing in docker build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, nginx, vite

When I build my vite image locally, with the command (from `package.json`)

`"vite_build:dev": "NODE_ENV=test env-cmd -f ./config/.env.dev react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8000 build"`,

it works. I can preview it locally and all works well. But if I do it in docker, I get an error:

```
=> ERROR [builder 7/7] RUN npm run vite_build:test                                              474.9s ------                                                                                                  
 > [builder 7/7] RUN npm run vite_build:test:                                                           #15 2.972                                                                                               #15 2.972 > client@0.1.0 vite_build:test                                                                
#15 2.972 > NODE_ENV=test env-cmd -f ./config/.env.test node --max_old_space_size=16384 ./node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js build                                                                                   
#15 2.972 
#15 7.937 vite v3.2.4 building for production...
#15 8.563 transforming...
#15 329.1 2:43:07 PM [vite] ✨ new dependencies optimized: @mui/styles, aws-sdk, @mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowDown, @mui/material/DialogContent, @mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowUp, ...and 20 more
#15 329.1 2:43:08 PM [vite] ✨ optimized dependencies changed. reloading
#15 474.5 npm notice 
#15 474.5 npm notice New major version of npm available! 7.15.1 -> 9.1.2
#15 474.5 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.1.2>
#15 474.5 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.1.2` to update!
#15 474.5 npm notice 
#15 474.6 npm ERR! path /usr/src/app
#15 474.6 npm ERR! command failed
#15 474.6 npm ERR! signal SIGKILL
#15 474.6 npm ERR! command sh -c NODE_ENV=test env-cmd -f ./config/.env.test node --max_old_space_size=16384 ./node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js build
#15 474.7 
#15 474.7 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#15 474.7 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-11-22T14_45_33_588Z-debug.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run vite_build:test]: exit code: 1
```

My build script:

```
"build:dev": "NODE_ENV=test env-cmd -f ./config/.env.dev react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8000 build",
```

This is my `vite.config.ts`:

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-default-export
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths(), svgr()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  preview: {
    port: 4000,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // This is needed for builds
      './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser',
    },
  },
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    sourcemap: true,
    commonjsOptions: {
      include: [],
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    disabled: false,
  },
});
```

My nginx config:

```
server {
     listen       80;
     server_name  localhost;
 
     location / {
         root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
         index  index.html index.htm;
         try_files $uri /index.html;                 
     }
 
     error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
     location = /50x.html {
         root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
     }
 }
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM node-16.3.0-alpine as builder
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY ./package*.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm run i
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run vite_build:dev

# production environment
FROM nginx-1.21.6-alpine
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Logically, I'd search in docker file, but I cannot see anything wrong with it. Furthermore, when I use the same dockerfile to build with react-scripts (as    `NODE_ENV=test env-cmd -f ./config/.env.dev react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8000 build` it works.

Answer (score 1):

You might have already solved this but the issue might be because the output directory for the build command with vite is dist and not build - as is the case with react scripts.

This command will therefore not work.

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Try this instead:

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```